# Get nearest time previous to current time which is divisible by 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time

I have a dataframe with a column which have time data in the format HH:MM:SS. Sample data is shown below for reference:

```
Time
09:25:03
09:28:40
09:36:12
09:36:14
09:41:10
09:51:00
09:58:48
10:00:11
10:00:17
10:21:44
10:21:53
10:32:58
11:08:59
11:45:55
11:49:14
12:18:54
12:21:22
13:05:47
13:19:37
13:19:57
13:25:22
14:21:10
```

I want to get the nearest time previous to current time which is divisible by 5. I want the output like below:

```
Time        Nearest_Time
09:25:03    09:25:00
09:28:40    09:25:00
09:36:12    09:35:00
09:36:14    09:35:00
09:41:10    09:40:00
09:51:00    09:50:00
09:58:48    09:50:00
10:00:11    10:00:00
10:00:17    10:00:00
10:21:44    10:20:00
10:21:53    10:20:00
10:32:58    10:30:00
11:08:59    11:05:00
11:45:55    11:45:00
11:49:14    11:45:00
12:18:54    12:15:00
12:21:22    12:20:00
13:05:47    13:05:00
13:19:37    13:15:00
13:19:57    13:15:00
13:25:22    13:25:00
14:21:10    14:20:00
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`dt.floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) setting `freq` to 5 minutes:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Time).dt.floor('5 min')

0    2020-02-14 09:25:00
1    2020-02-14 09:25:00
2    2020-02-14 09:35:00
3    2020-02-14 09:35:00
4    2020-02-14 09:40:00
5    2020-02-14 09:50:00
6    2020-02-14 09:55:00
7    2020-02-14 10:00:00
8    2020-02-14 10:00:00
9    2020-02-14 10:20:00
10   2020-02-14 10:20:00
11   2020-02-14 10:30:00
12   2020-02-14 11:05:00
13   2020-02-14 11:45:00
14   2020-02-14 11:45:00
15   2020-02-14 12:15:00
16   2020-02-14 12:20:00
17   2020-02-14 13:05:00
18   2020-02-14 13:15:00
19   2020-02-14 13:15:00
20   2020-02-14 13:25:00
21   2020-02-14 14:20:00
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change `Time` to `timedelta` and do normal arithmetic operations:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])

period = pd.to_timedelta('5M')
df['nearest_past'] = df['Time'] // period * period

# floor also works
# df['nearest_past'] = df['Time'].dt.floor(period)
```

Output:

```
       Time nearest_past
0  09:25:03     09:25:00
1  09:28:40     09:25:00
2  09:36:12     09:35:00
3  09:36:14     09:35:00
4  09:41:10     09:40:00
5  09:51:00     09:50:00
6  09:58:48     09:55:00
7  10:00:11     10:00:00
8  10:00:17     10:00:00
9  10:21:44     10:20:00
10 10:21:53     10:20:00
11 10:32:58     10:30:00
12 11:08:59     11:05:00
13 11:45:55     11:45:00
14 11:49:14     11:45:00
15 12:18:54     12:15:00
16 12:21:22     12:20:00
17 13:05:47     13:05:00
18 13:19:37     13:15:00
19 13:19:57     13:15:00
20 13:25:22     13:25:00
21 14:21:10     14:20:00
```